# Can we get Discourse links onebox in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I just [found out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14701676#14701676) that [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) links don't onebox in chat.

Can we add this site to the list of sites that onebox?